# Ansible Patching Failed

Tags: rhel, ansible

I have problem with security patching via Ansible. I have two machines

1) Ansible master server (Version 2.8.4) I want to apply security update to server with RHEL8. But patching failed, see below error:

```
fatal: [lrhel8.exam.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failures": [], "msg": "Depsolve Error occured: \n Problem 1: cannot install both bind-license-32:9.11.4-26.P2.el8.noarch and bind-license-32:9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1.noarch\n  - package bind-libs-32:9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1.x86_64 requires bind-license = 32:9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1, but none of the providers can be installed\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package bind-license-32:9.11.4-16.P2.el8.noarch\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package bind-libs-32:9.11.4-16.P2.el8.x86_64\n Problem 2: cannot install both gvfs-client-1.36.2-6.el8.x86_64 and gvfs-client-1.36.2-2.el8_0.1.x86_64\n  - package gvfs-1.36.2-6.el8.x86_64 requires gvfs-client(x86-64) = 1.36.2-6.el8, but none of the providers can be installed\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package gvfs-client-1.36.2-1.el8.x86_64\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package gvfs-1.36.2-1.el8.x86_64\n Problem 3: cannot install both python3-libs-3.6.8-15.1.el8.x86_64 and python3-libs-3.6.8-2.el8_0.x86_64\n  - package platform-python-3.6.8-2.el8_0.x86_64 requires python3-libs(x86-64) = 3.6.8-2.el8_0, but none of the providers can be installed\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package python3-libs-3.6.8-1.el8.x86_64\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package platform-python-3.6.8-1.el8.x86_64\n Problem 4: package systemd-container-239-18.el8.x86_64 requires systemd(x86-64) = 239-18.el8, but none of the providers can be installed\n  - cannot install both systemd-239-18.el8.x86_64 and systemd-239-13.el8_0.3.x86_64\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package systemd-container-239-13.el8.x86_64\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package systemd-239-13.el8.x86_64\n Problem 5: package bind-libs-32:9.11.4-26.P2.el8.x86_64 requires bind-libs-lite(x86-64) = 32:9.11.4-26.P2.el8, but none of the providers can be installed\n  - package bind-utils-32:9.11.4-26.P2.el8.x86_64 requires bind-libs(x86-64) = 32:9.11.4-26.P2.el8, but none of the providers can be installed\n  - cannot install both bind-libs-lite-32:9.11.4-26.P2.el8.x86_64 and bind-libs-lite-32:9.11.4-17.P2.el8_0.1.x86_64\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package bind-utils-32:9.11.4-16.P2.el8.x86_64\n  - cannot install the best update candidate for package bind-libs-lite-32:9.11.4-16.P2.el8.x86_64", "rc": 1, "results": []}
```

But if i try update of whole server (`yum update`), it's ok without problem.

2) Server with RHEL8

`yum update --security` passed without problem.

Could please someone help with this problem? Thanks

Role (TASK):

```
- name: Ensure all packages are updated
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    conf_file: "{{ conf_file | default(omit) }}"
    disable_gpg_check: "{{ disable_gpg_check }}"
    disablerepo: "{{ disablerepo | default(omit, true) }}"
    enablerepo: "{{ enablerepo | default(omit, true) }}"
    exclude: "{{ exclude | default(omit, true) }}"
    security: "{{ security_only }}"
    update_cache: "{{ update_cache }}"
    validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}"
    skip_broken: "{{ skip_broken }}"
  register: yum_result
```

### Role(defaults):

```
disable_gpg_check: false
update_cache: false
validate_certs: true
var_free_space: 524288  # 512 MB = 512 * 1024 KB
security_only: true
skip_broken: true
...
```

Playbook:

```
- role: yum-update
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
  tags:
    - yum-update
```

Comment: I would start by looking into why `ansible` thinks it needs to install two conflicting versions of `bind-license`.  That would require more details about how you are using `ansible` to do your security patching.  Your `ansible` seems to be confused with two different versions of RHEL8 (8.0.1905 vs 8.1.1911).

Comment: Report above edited.

Comment: Could you also post which YUM repositories you are using for your updates?  You have `enablerepo` and `disablerepo` in your `ansible` role but you do not show what those values are.

Comment: Enabled repos:

`Repo Name: HP Firmware 8Server
Repo Name: Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.8 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.5 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
Repo Name: HP Scripting tools 8Server x86_64
Repo Name: HP SPP 8Server x86_64
Repo Name: HP SUM 8Server
Repo Name: EPEL 8Server x86_64`

Comment: I do not see any glaring conflicts from the names.  Check to make sure non of those repositories are pinned to a specific version of RedHat8 (or that they are all pinned to the same specific version).